# Unity. Игра под андроид не запускается

Tags: unity3d

После перехода с версии 2017 на 2018 игра под андроид почему-то не запускается. Билдится без проблем, в самой юнити игра работает, но на устройстве при открытии игры сначала запускается игра, точнее выходит логотип Unity и после этого вылетает на рабочий стол, но в процессах игра все равно остается, при попытке перейти в игру снова выкидывает на рабочий стол.
В чем может быть проблема ?
Вот настройки билда - http://joxi.ru/5md0VDnI3vNPzm

Comment: если раннее запускали игру на данном устройстве то почистите кеш/создавайемые игрой файлы

Comment: Проблема может быть в том, что в редакторе и на устройстве игра обычно ведёт себя по разному. Например Awake у классов может в другом порядке отработать или ещё что. Подключайте устройство через USB к компу, ставьте какой-нибудь софт вроде mLogcat, фильтруйте логи по тегу Unity и смотрите, что там ваша игра выдаёт в логи при попытке её открыть. Ошибки в логах будут аналогичны ошибкам в редакторе

Comment: Виталий Шебаниц. Кеш почистил - не помогло

Comment: M.Green спасибо, буду пробовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Краш происходил из-за того что я не установил ресурсы для Google Play Games, поэтому и крашило.